# Appium: Unable to Switch focus to Phone Gap InApp Browser from the current Application

Tags: android, cordova, selenium, appium

I am working on a Hybrid Application built on Phone Gap. 
After opening the Application, I can find two different Context in the App (i.e., NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_...)
I switched to Webview Context and my test works as intended.
There is an external link in the Application which opens a WebApp in PhoneGap InApp Browser (Browser popup runs internally on the Application).
In the Chrome://inspect screen, now I can see two different Browser tabs under a WebView.
[Click here to view the Chrome Inspect Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2kQg.jpg).
As shown in the image, I got two different tabs under a webview and My Test runs properly in the **WELCOME** tab and when the external URL **Primary** opens in InApp browser my test fails.
Getting the Contexthandles() shows only the contexts shown in the beginning.
The error I am getting is '`Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression`'.
Could someone please help me on how to switch over from one tab to another tab in single Webview.

Thanks in Advance
Senthil

Comment: Can yo you try getting the window handles for the browser? `java.util.Set window_ids = driver.getWindowHandles();` will get available window handles. So you should be able to switch to the correct tab. (tab is treated as a window in selenium/appium). You need to be in the WEB context for executing the above.

Comment: @debugger89 Thanks for your prompt reply. Few days back I have used this method and there was no luck for me. But now after making the system wait for the page to load and using WindowHandle() everything works fine :)